# Java classes to MongoDB "DDL" generation support

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to know whether **Spring Data MongoDB** supports such a feature as **generating DDL (mongodb document structures) from java classes**.

In other words something similar to Hibernate's **hbm2ddl.auto** capability.

Comment: Not at this time.  Spring Data gives you the ability to do the templating and other object conversions.  But no auto DDLs yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data gives you the ability to do the templating and other object conversions. But no auto DDLs yet.